# 俺は自分だけが勝手に高ぶってしまわないよう >>What does this mean ?( In order to prevent myself from getting too excited ?)

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

> 俺は自分だけが勝手に高ぶってしまわないよう

What does this mean? My guess is "In order to prevent myself from getting too excited"?

If you can please break down the grammar for me to understand

Comment: TIL 高ぶる also means "to get excited", "to be stirred/worked up".  

Comment: Could you copy the part that follows?

Comment: Let me say this again, this site is not a translation (or translation check) service. Instead of asking others to break down everything, please narrow down the grammar point or phrase **you** don't understand. In this case, your translation seems already spot-on to me, so I don't understand **why** you are asking this. If your translation doesn't fit the context, please provide the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you are pretty close, but I would translate it as:

> It seems I am the only one who did not get completely excited

Let's talk about the grammar and why I think this. Full sentence again for reference:

> 俺は自分だけが勝手に高ぶってしまわないよう

The grammar break down:

> 俺 = I/Me
>
> は = Particle declaring that the previous thing (I/Me) is the overall topic
>
> 自分 = Oneself
>
> だけ = Only
>
> が = Particle setting the previous thing (only oneself) the subject of the sentence
>
> 勝手に = One's own way / Willfully
>
> 高ぶって = 高ぶる in the て form. Means to be / get excited and additionally XYZ.
> The additionally XYZ part comes from it being in the て form
>
> しまわない = しまう in the negative form. しまう Means to do completely / accidently.
> Taking it means "completely" here. So we are saying has not/did not do completely
>
> よう = Seems
> I say "seems" here because I'm assuming this is a complete sentence.
> Any left off parts can easily change the meaning

Now let's put it all together and convert it into "English":

> I, only myself, in my own way did not excited and to completeness it seems.

"Cleaning" it up to sound natural:

> It seems I am the only one who didn't get completely excited.

Comment: I doubt this よう means "seems". よう of ようにする is more likely. We would need the part that follows to be sure, though.

Comment: @aguijonazo You definitely could be right! Thought about that too, but I assumed it was a complete sentence and the だ/です was just left off

Answer (score 0):

Here is another sentence break down which I got from 1 guy in Discord ,in case anyone on internet want a reference . This is just MC thought about his action, could be "excited about emotion /he's acting too fast because excitement

自分だけが Only myself

勝手に arbitrarily

高ぶってしまわない　> 高ぶる to be excited + しまう involuntary action + ない negative

よう in order to / so

"So I won't get all excited by myself"